# Teradata - Column datatypes not copied for views

Tags: teradata

I am trying to create view from table as below

```
CREATE TABLE tb
(
  a INTEGER,
  b INTEGER
)

CREATE VIEW vtb AS
(SELECT *
 FROM tb);
```

And then when I executed the following command the type of the column is null

> help view vtb;

[image]

Is there a way to copy the column datatypes while creating the view ?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, other than `help column databasename.tablename.*`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your reply, But How can i use Help in create the view syntax ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misread your post, not sure I understand you?

Comment: @Andrew, I updated the question with the screenshot with the result of `help view vtb;` what i need to be the type column to have value not null

Comment: The columns have data types, the help view command doesn't show them. The column types are only defined explicitly in the base table.

Comment: Teradata does not store column metadata for views, only the column names and definition text. `HELP COLUMN` evaluates the view to dynamically determine the data types (similar to issuing a `PREPARE` from the client).